# pivoting and multi-indexing

Tags: pandas, pivot, reshape, multi-index

How do I transform a pandas dataframe that is in the following format:

```
Index   Code   Year   Week   Count
    0   AE    2005     1      0
    1   AE    2005     2      0
    2   AE    2005     3      2
    3   AE    2005     4      0
    4   AE    2005     5      0
    .....
    51  AE    2005     52     1
    52  AE    2006     1      3
    53  AE    2006     2      0
    54  AE    2006     3      1
    55  AE    2006     4      0
    56  AE    2006     5      0
    .....
    102  AE    2006     52     1
    103  AU    2005     1      0
    104  AU    2005     2      0
    105  AU    2005     3      2
    106  AU    2005     4      0
    107  AU    2005     5      0
    .....
    153  AU    2005     52     1
    154  AU    2006     1      3
    155  AU    2006     2      0
    156  AU    2006     3      1
    157  AU    2006     4      0
    158  AU    2006     5      0
    .....
    203  AU    2006     52     1
```

There are multiple codes, multiple years, 52 weeks entries for each year and a count value for each week

The required format:

```
      Year      2005                  2006
      Week      1     2    3  ... 52  1     2    3 ... 
Code
AE              0     0    2  ... 0   0     1    2 ... 
AU
...
ZC
```

I have tried looking up different solutions here as well as have tried `pivot`, `pivot_table`, combinations of `stack` and `unstack`, but haven't been able to workout the solution :(.

Comment: @Wen, I have seen that post and none of the scenarios seem to match my case. The pivoting cases there include aggregations, I can't aggregate.

Comment: Would you like me reopen it then ?

Comment: That would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `set_index` and `stack`

```
df.set_index(['Code','Year','Week']).Count.unstack([1,2])
Year 2005            
Week    1  2  3  4  5
Code                 
AE      0  0  2  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks Wen, this is giving me the following error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Count'

Comment: @Kam check your columns , whether it contain space or not

Comment: not sure what are you asking? Do you mean space in column names? The answer is no. The code column is alpha-numeric, all other columns are integer values

Comment: @Kam can you try my code with your sample data frame , check whether it work or not

Comment: I have updated the sample data frame to better explain what I am trying to do.